# office365 Word / Excel export to PDF format

Tags: pdf, office365, export

Is it possible to export office365 Word / Excel to PDF format? I'm using Czech localization and I see only OASIS Open Document Format formats (`.odt` and `.ods`) when looking into File -> Save as.

UPDATE: The menu I see (yes, it's in Czech)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select 'Print' and when choosing 'Printer' change to 'Microsoft Print to PDF'
[print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzEdm.png)

[Print to PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuI6B.png)

Answer (score 0):

You don't want the *Save* options. You want the *Export* options. From there, you'll see an option for PDFs.

Comment: I don't see _Export_ options :(.

Comment: @pevik Show screenshot of the menu where you've found the save option?

Comment: Added, you'll have to translate it.

Comment: @pevik Do you currently have a file open in Excel?

Comment: I see (comparing to my Excel) zavrit = Close; domu = Home; nori = New; otevrit = Open; informace = Information; ultozit jako = Save As; tisk = Print; moznosti = Options; sdilet = Share; I cannot find aplikaci .    @pevik - Anything under Save as (sub option) or the Options settigs?

Comment: Yes, the menu is from opened Excel (office 365). And no, it's not on all options, believe me I searched deeply in all options before asking. Maybe some licencing issue.